# SSIS: Data conversion failed from a Flat File Source

Tags: windows, ssis, bids, flat-file

The following are the errors that had occurred while processing the flat file:

- Error: 0xC02020A1 at Task, File [1]: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Column 0" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
- Error: 0xC020902A at Task, File [1]: The "output column "Column 0" (14)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Column 0" (14)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
- Error: 0xC0202092 at Task, File [1]: An error occurred while processing file "**filepath**" on data row 1.
- Error: 0xC0047038 at Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Retrieve Input Batch File" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Source File is a **Flat File**
Data Type properties for External Column and Output Column is identical:

```
Data Type: String [DT_STR]
```

Length is 1143

I've tried to experiment with the values in the properties, but I got no luck.
What could be the reason for the error?

In addition, I tried to test 2 files. First file got success result, while the latter did not. Difference between them is, the first one is Dos\Windows, while the other is UNIX. Does it affect the behavior of the flat file?

Comment: Reading the first error seems that you're doing an import, and the field In the table has a smaller size RESPECT on the contents of the file column.

Comment: Yes,Alex. I'm doing an import, however, the input column and the output column are configured to have the same length that is long enough to cater the input data.

Comment: Do you have errors in Flat File Connection Manager if you make a previw of the UNIX file?

Comment: No errors were reported, however, the information is printed in a single line...then, there is an ellipses in the end the output preview window.

Comment: Then the system does not recognize row delimiters {CR}{LF}; are there column separators in the file? Probably you need to model the connection so that the rows are recognized..

Comment: ooooh, I see. Is that also the reason why truncation occurs? Column separators were not set since the whole row is transferred to a single column.

Comment: Probably a unique line is recognized by a length too large to be managed. Try to verify if there are row separators in the files: tab Columns -> Row delimiter in Flat File Connection Manager.

Comment: This is noted, Alex. Thank you so much. The issue was resolved by modifying the input file having line endling {CR} {LF}.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your flat file connection manager>>> Flat file Source Editor then >>> Click on Error Output >>>> and then to the column in question and select Ignore Failure. This worked for me. (That is if the column size is right)

Answer (score -1):

[Flat File Source [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlkGp.png)] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "rowguid" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

[Flat File Source [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlkGp.png)] Error: The "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[rowguid]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[rowguid]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

[Flat File Source [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlkGp.png)] Error: An error occurred while processing file "D:\Desktop\SSIS\output\PersonPassword_31072023.csv" on data row 2.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[Image: Error that I faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROkZY.png)

[Image: See my destination table the maximum length of type varchar length is 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlkGp.png)

[Image: And source table value of that column length is minimum 34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zslPu.png)

[Image: I ALTER that column in destination table: the length 30 to 50 of varchar datatype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shJSX.png)

After that the task start successfully with no error.